# Rewrite rule ignoring /index

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have simple `.htaccess` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/static/).+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/media/).+ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Everything works properly (page/edit, users/show ...), but when I open browser on URL `index/something` a will get empty `$_GET`.

Where can be problem please?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work if your url has /index/something?

Comment: Yes, when I open browser on URL /index/something or index/something2 or index/, I will get empty $_GET in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an issue with the Server config as "index" might be the default file. So the routing is being done due to the configuration and not due to the htaccess.

Try checking what file names are treated as valid default names by Apache. Also, what happens if you add /index(.*) as a separate RewriteRule?

Comment: Where can I find "default names" at Apache conf file?

Comment: Shoule be the DirectoryIndex in httpd.conf

Comment: `<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>`

Comment: Did you try creating a separate rewrite rule for index? That might help.

Comment: I tried add this rule into .htaccess `RewriteRule index(.*) index.php?query=index/$1 [L]` and I will get $_GET["query"] == 'index/.php/something'

Comment: How about `RewriteRule index/(.*) index.php?query=index/$1`

Comment: Ok, I used your rule, but the $_GET is empty (index/something).

Answer (score 1):

Your current rewrite rule doesn't take the case of /index/something into account. If you were to just use /something then it would be redirected to index.php?query=something. Try adding this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

EDIT:
Based on the comments we're seeing that Apache is using /index as an alias for /index.php. As a temporary workaround until you figure out the needed changes for the Apache configuration you could probably do:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ index.php?query=index/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [L]
```

Putting that first rule ahead of the RewriteCond lines will catch the /index case and the rest will be caught by your original rules.

Comment: No, I think you didnt understand my problem. I need to "route" everything (expect static and media) to ?query= to index.php. Everything works properly, like users/edit ($_GET["query"] == "users/edit") but index/something not. When I open URL /index/something then $_GET is empty.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. You should be seeing "/index/something" as the value of $_GET['query'] but you're not.

Comment: Exactly. I think the rewrite rule is OK, but the problem will be at httpd.conf.

Comment: I appears that Apache thinks /index is a valid file or directory. What happens if you temporarily remove the RewriteCond lines in front of your rule (!-f and !-d)? Does that allow the index/something query to go through?

Comment: Ok, I removed !-f and !-d. Now when I open index/something I will get $_GET 
  `'query' => string 'index.php/something'`

Comment: Ok, I edited .htaccess with your rules, but when I open index/something, the $_GET is empty.